# How to create a synonym in mysql

Tags: mysql, synonym

I have a view in database `B` which I use in database `A`.

I would like to create a synonym to this view. Because right now each time I have to write the query like this

```
Select * from DBNAME.VIEWNAME
```

rather I just want to be able to write

```
SELECT * FROM MYSYNONYMNAME
```

Is that possible to do in mysql? I didn't see much in the manual..

Comment: what do you mean by synonym? there are many definitions of it.

Comment: sorry, I meant synonym as in a name pointing to something. I've updated the question with an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not supported in MySQL.

Comment: really? is there no way of achieving this? it seems like a very basic thing for a db...

Comment: @Sharma: for "mature" dbms :-) postgresql, oracle, sql server - all these have a such feature. Mysql chose its own way, as usually ;-)

Comment: [Create a synonym in MySQL](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/02/05/create-a-synonym-in-mysql/)

Comment: @J W: and for a table? PS: perhaps it's possible to use views, but then OP may have issues with performance ...

Comment: yeah, I did come across that link but it was doing it for functions and not tables or views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to create synonyms in mysql like [it's possible in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm)

Comment: I'm sure there is a good reason behind it, but thats just unfortunate. thanks though

Comment: @Sharma: if you see something strange - then you can explain it with just simple: "in mysql it usually not like in other DMBS"

Answer (score 4):

Apparently a `VIEW` may work as a `SYNONYM`:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `MYSYNONYMNAME` $$
CREATE ALGORITHM=MERGE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `MYSYNONYMNAME` AS
SELECT * FROM DBNAME.VIEWNAME $$
```

Not sure of performance or how far you can get away stacking views within views etc.  Also might need to recreate when base table columns change.

See: http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2013/11/24/mysql-synonym/