# How to create synonym for table and columns of this table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, synonym

I know in oracle I can do something like this:

```
create synonym Cutomers for LongTablePrefix_Customers
```

Now, I can write sql statements like

```
select * from Customers
```

instead of monstrous

```
select * from LongTablePrefix_Customers
```

I realized, that mysql have same functionality there. I can create synonim for table and this is nice, but... But fields names are looks like `LongTableName_ID`, `LongTableName_Name` etc. Is it possible to create synonyms for fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a synonym in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777420/how-to-create-a-synonym-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a view

```
create view Customers show select LongTableName_ID as ID, LongTableName_Name as Name from LongTablePrefix_Customers
```

Synonyms are not possible in MySQL.

Comment: Well, as a variant... But is it possible to create synonyms?

Comment: There are no synonyms possible in MySQL

Comment: MySQL is limited...2 alternatives, this view or install postgres instead

Answer (score 0):

Create a Data Access Layer in front of your MySQL/MariaDB database and then you can set up multiple routes to the same underlying table or fields. Not a quick solution, and only answers your question in a roundabout way, but it is an option and it works. [LoopBack](https://loopback.io/) works well for it.