# JPA Change entity table name base on request parameter

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jpa

Our database at the moment have 2 schema, one for production, one for testing, identical table but different data.

For server side, we use RoutingDatasource to manage the data. Each request have a parameter to know which database to access, like "prod" or "test". The parameter then store in ThreadLocal. Our RoutingDatasource will get this parmeter out, depend on the value and return the correct datasource. So we only need one mapping entity and one CrudRepository for same table in both schema.

But for some (stupid) reason, we were asked to merge both schema into one schema, having a prefix in front of each table, like PROD_TABLE1, TEST_TABLE1, PROD_TABLE2, TEST_TABLE2, etc.

So i want to ask, how can we keep only 1 entity, 1 repository for each table with this requirement? We don't want to clone code, create too many class inherit the existing one just to map to the second table. @SecondaryTable seem not what we looking for.

===============================

UPDATE 1:

I'm looking at PhysicalNamingStrategy, able to add a prefix to table name. But this only run once when they init the EntityManager. So is there any other way to add a prefix to table on each request?

===============================

UPDATE 2:
I try with something like this:

```
@Table(name = "##schema##TABLE1")
```

Then add a Hibernate interceptor to our project. When prepare statement, we get the parameter from ThreadLocal, then replace the "##schema##" part with correct prefix. Using this way, everything work, but i don't really like this solution.

Anyone have any better way to do it?

Comment: I'd revert it on the previous case using two empty schemas with synonyms or views pointing to the tables.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber our customer ( who hire us ) does not give us more than 1 schema. If we have 2 empty schema then we would rather have 2 schema for production and testing seperate instead

Comment: Well than you may say you need not two schemas but only two database users.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber 2 database user? each can work with different set of table? What can that help when the problem here is that i have table with different name but same structure and want to use only 1 object mapping, 1 repository? Can you tell me more? Also i have a work around, you can check my update, but still waiting for a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of the *security* I'd never recommend to mix productive and test data in one schema, but anyway if you plan to do so, here is a simple way how to *pretend* you access the data with **different  OWNERs**.

Lets assume you have a application schema `APP` with two tables `TEST_TAB1` and `PROD_TAB1`.

```
-- connect as APP
create table app.prod_tab1 as
select 'prod' col1 from dual;

create table app.test_tab1 as
select 'test' col1 from dual;
```

You have also two users, say `PROD_USR` and `TEST_USR`, that access the data  as  follows:

```
--- connect with test_usr
select * from app.test_tab1;
COL1
----
test 

--- connect with prod_usr
select * from app.prod_tab1;
COL1
----
prod
```

So, now you have the problem, that the tables have different names for different environments.

What you need, is to have for both users test_usr and prod_usr the priviledge `create synonym` and define following synonyms:

```
-- test_usr
create synonym test_usr.tab1 for app.test_tab1;
-- prod_usr
create synonym prod_usr.tab1 for app.prod_tab1;
```

Now the access goes with a unique name and different schema:

```
--- connect with test_usr
select * from test_usr.tab1;
COL1
----
test

--- connect with prod_usr
select * from prod_usr.tab1;
COL1
----
prod
```

If you say, no we do not have the two different access users, we access both environments with the schema owner `APP`, the please re-read my first sentence.

Comment: oh so we create a synonym for each user. we have RoutingDatasource at the moment so we only need to change the account setting for each datasource and everything should be done. Seem good for me but we would need to do this for every single table and sequence right? Also i need to ask our customer if they allow to create 2 user for us. If they allow then i will accept your answer. Sorry as i can't do this right now as i can't make the decision

Comment: Just have another question, is there any other way like create synonym for MySQL. As our customer said before that there a chance that they going to change from Oracle to MySql in few months time. So if not then we will have to find another solution if they really going to change database, like sticking with the work around of add the prefix to table name when preparestatement

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777420/how-to-create-a-synonym-in-mysql) you may use `view`s with the same effect. You can do it in Oracle as well.

Comment: asked customer and they rejected the ideal as creating new user/schema process would take them few weeks ( that what they said ) while they only give us only 1 week to complete this task. and other reason blah blah. but this is still a solution for us if anything like this happen in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Putting my own workaround here for anyone if they need:

First put a prefix "**##prefix##**" into every entity object:

```
@Table(name = "##prefix##TEST_TABLE_1")
```

Create a hibernate interceptor class extend EmptyInterceptor and override method **onPrepareStatement**. Here get the prefix from ThreadLocal ( set when receive the request beforehand ) and replace it with the "##prefix##" in table name.

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Override
    public String onPrepareStatement(String sql) {
        String prefix = ThreadLocal.getDbPrefix();
        sql = sql.replaceAll("##schema##", prefix + "_");
        return super.onPrepareStatement(sql);
    }
}
```

Like this, the query will point to correct table.

And config to EntityManagerFactory: (You can set this in xml file too)

```
properties.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", "mypackage.HibernateInterceptor");
```