# Dynamic Table name in Spring boot JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, repository, hibernate-5.x

My requirement is to change the table name while inserting the records.

I want to change the table name to users_myCompany where myCompany will change for each and every query.

**Example:**
I have a api called user/settings, User does a api call from company_1 the table name for the entity **Users** must be set as Users_company_1 and if the user is doing a api call from company 2, the table name for the entity must be set as users_company_2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Put in some trial and run you have done. Show some efforts which you have done.

Comment: Got the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51417368/jpa-change-entity-table-name-base-on-request-parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In @Table(name = "tableName") - make "tableName" a variable in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444962/in-tablename-tablename-make-tablename-a-variable-in-jpa)